# How to play iOS system sounds from Adobe Air

Tags: ios, air, audio

Is it possible to play the iOS default sounds from an Adobe Air app?

Of course I could always find the sound files (somehow) and import them into the Air app, but that's not what I'm asking.

I have been investigating into native extensions, but couldn't find any that does just that.

Comment: What do you mean by  " iOS default sounds "? the music files imported/purchased by user or iOS system ringtones and sounds ?

Comment: No, I mean for example the "click" sound when writing with the keyboard, or the default alarm sounds.

Comment: I am afraid you are not allowed to have access to this kind of sounds. But I may be wrong.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I thought... but I asked anyway.